# mod_rewrite: HTTPS for only one page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, redirect

I want to redirect to HTTPS only /login page. Rest of pages needs to be HTTP.

.htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /login
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/login
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. When I go to /login I was redirected to example.com/index.php 
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is there an actual (physical) `/login` folder or file in your directory? I suppose not, so your `/login` request is finally captured by the last rewrite rule and redirected to index.php.

Try adding this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/login` above this line:`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` ( or just handle the login request differently )

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `L` flag in your last rule have your code like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /login [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/login [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```